# Why the huge thrust difference between a Sea level and Vacuum J-2 engine?

Tags: launch, engine-design, j-2, saturn-v

Looking at the [Wikipedia page for the J-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_J-2) (one engine was used on the Saturn V third stage, and 5 engines on the second stage) it gets about 232Klbs thrust in vacuum, but at sea level, only 109KLbs thrust.

That is a pretty wild performance swing.

Why such a difference? If you compare the Vacuum Merlin's vs the sea level Merlin's performance you get a much smaller swing in performance.

I am guessing it is because there never was a sea level optimized J-2 engine (it was meant as an upper stage engine) so the sea level number may be spurious or only from test stands.

Comment: This, in a nutshell, is the problem that linear aerospike engines are supposed to solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Designed for high altitude low ambient pressure, I assume. The primary [optimization is in the nozzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine#Back_pressure_and_optimal_expansion):

> For optimal performance the pressure of the gas at the end of the nozzle should just equal the ambient pressure: if the exhaust's pressure is lower than the ambient pressure, then the vehicle will be slowed by the difference in pressure between the top of the engine and the exit; on the other hand, if the exhaust's pressure is higher, then exhaust pressure that could have been converted into thrust is not converted, and energy is wasted.
>
> To maintain this ideal of equality between the exhaust's exit pressure and the ambient pressure, the diameter of the nozzle would need to increase with altitude, giving the pressure a longer nozzle to act on (and reducing the exit pressure and temperature). This increase is difficult to arrange in a lightweight fashion, although is routinely done with other forms of jet engines. In rocketry a lightweight compromise nozzle is generally used and some reduction in atmospheric performance occurs when used at other than the 'design altitude' or when throttled.

Comment: So you expect a reduction in behavior for a vacuum optimized engine/nozzle, but this is a 50% cut in performance.  More than usual.

Comment: J-2 fires at a very low chamber pressure (30 bar/435 psi) compared to something like the SSME (206 bar/3000 psi); I think that's the main factor in the sea level specific impulse dropoff.

Answer (score 9):

There is another important variable besides chamber pressure and nozzle design to consider--how the engine pumps the propellants into the chamber. The J-2 engine, like the lower stage (and much more powerful but lower ISP kerosene burning F-1 engine) used a gas generator (basically burning oxygen and fuel, here hydrogen) to drive a turbine that pumped the oxygen and hydrogen into itself and the main chamber. The F-1 (using kerosene instead of hydrogen) was designed with high enough gas generator pressure to drive the pumps at launch, but the J-2, designed for vacuum operations, used a lower gas generator pressure to drive its pumps. The very low sea level ISP reflects not just the usual "back up" of rockets by sea level air pressure but also a turbo pump rendered anemic by the same back pressure.

Just today I downloaded software called RPA that simulates rocket chambers and nozzle performance for a wide variety of propellant types and chamber pressures and other conditions. My attempt to simulate the J-2A engine (an upgrade of the J-2) suggests, if I did it correctly, that a reasonable sea level ISP for the J series engines with the same type of chamber and nozzle would be a bit under 300 seconds, a reduction of 31 percent. In terms of thrust in Klbs, that would suggest a bit under 160, so at just under 110 poor pump performance at sea level apparently dings it another 22 percent.

Comment: What's the J2's gas generator chamber pressure?  It would have to be mighty low for an ambient pressure difference of 15 psi to be a large fraction.

Comment: Where did you get the RPA sortware? We have a meta post that is collecting this sort of thing.

Comment: @JerardPuckett [Main page](http://lpre.de/), [RPA page itself](http://www.propulsion-analysis.com/index.htm)